# Blob download doesn't work on iOS Chrome or Firefox

Tags: ios, google-chrome, firefox, download, blob

On iOS, in both Chrome and Firefox, saving a blob to a file, using the technique of embedding an object URL in a hidden link in the DOM and programmatically clicking on it, does not work. The following happens:

- JSON (blob of type application/json) displays the JSON in plain text
  but does not download it.
- An XLSX spreadsheet (blob of type
  application/octet-stream) does nothing.
- PNG (blob of type image/png)
  displays the image but does not download it.
- SVG (blob of type
  image/svg+xml) displays the image but does not download it.

The download technique works on iOS Safari as well as all the following desktop browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge.

Here is the code:

```
const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const tempLink = document.createElement("a");
tempLink.style.display = "none";
tempLink.href = blobURL;
tempLink.setAttribute("download", filename);
tempLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
document.body.appendChild(tempLink);

tempLink.click();
tempLink.remove();
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
```

What can I do to enable the user to download data created in the browser on iOS Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: The FileReader API provides a workaround which works on both iOS Chrome and Firefox. Unfortunately the workaround is a really horrible experience for the user, requiring them to download a file called "document", open the Files app, go to:
Locations -> "On my ", open the Chrome folder, and rename the file (append the .json extension).

Comment: Even more unfortunately, this workaround cannot be made available on iOS Firefox because the user agent string provided by iOS Firefox is identical to that provided by iOS Safari, and therefore there appears to be no way of uniquely identifying Firefox on iOS.